# getText is not a function error - Protractor (javascript)

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, protractor, automated-tests

I have node.js installed and protractor installed. I have experience with selenium-webdriver but Protractor is driving me nuts!!! I am also not that familiar with javascript.

This is what my code looks like:

```
describe('My app', function() {

    var result = element(by.id('result-name'));
    var enterBtn = element(by.id('enter'));
    var clearFieldBtn = element(by.id('clear-field'); 

    it('should bring up components on load', function() {
        browser.get(`http://localhost:${process.env.PORT}`);
        browser.wait(until.titleContains('Sample App'), 500);
        browser.wait(until.presenceOf(browser.element(by.id('my-test-app'))), 500);

        expect(enterBtn).isPresent;
      });

    it('result should equal username', function () {
        browser.get(`http://localhost:${process.env.PORT}`);

        expect(clearFieldBtn).isPresent;
        expect(result.getText()).toEqual('John Smith'); //both tests pass without this line of code   

    });

});
```

The last line "expect(result.getText()).toEqual('John Smith');" throws me an error. I get:

```
expect(...).toEqual is not a function
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I have spent a couple of hours trying to find a solution and trying different things.

I also wanted to implement the isPresent function how it's done in the api docs which is like this: expect($('.item').isPresent()).toBeTruthy();

I tried to do:

```
expect(clearFieldBtn).isPresent().toBeTruthy();
```

But I get that isPresent is not a function...

Comment: Your title is misleading.  The question/error isn't about `getText()`, its about your jasmine functions `toEqual`, `toContain` etc.

Comment: Also can you please post your config, what test library are you using?

Answer (score 3):

The expect above that line seems poor. It should read

```
expect(clearFieldBtn.isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
```

not sure if that is causing the weird error on the line below...just thought I would throw it out there. All your protractor APIs need be be called within the expect because `isPresent` is not a attribute of `expect`

Comment: also noticed that your element for `clearFieldBtn` is missing a parenthesis

Comment: Ahh thanks, I missed the paranthesis when I copied it over. For the toBeTruthy line, when I run it, I get that it's not a function...idk what's going on.

Comment: if you just run `expect(true).toBeTruthy()` in its own it-block, what do you get

Comment: Yea, sounds like you don't even has Jasmine installed if you can't access those functions

Comment: @Gunderson I have Protractor  installed. Shouldn't I be able to use Jasmine functions that way? I'll check the configurations when I get back on my computer. The Protractor api docs uses an almost identical scenario where they locate an element, use getText, and uses toEqual for the test.

Comment: Protractor is just a test framework, you need a test library to go along with it.  `getText` and the Protractor functions are fine, but you need a library (jasmine) to use `toEqual`, `toContain` etc.  Protractor is supposed to use Jasmine by default, but you should declare one in your config to be sure, i.e. `framework: 'jasmine'`

Comment: Actually, I guess `describe` and `it` also come from jasmine, so maybe that's not the issue since those aren't throwing errors.... this is a weird issue.

Comment: @Gunderson Hey, is it possible to message you off this site? You seem like an expert and I am still stuck with this stuff...

Comment: @LostJon I get the same error message >_< TypeError: expect(...).toBeTruthy is not a function

Comment: that is a bit wild to me @learningruby347. as previously stated, jasmine comes w/ protractor...for further diagnoses, can you give the protractor version you are working w/? one thing to think about, when you initialize your elements, you should do this within a `beforeAll` block...since they return promises, there could be something funky there....Also, shouldnt the element definitions be made AFTER the `browser.get` call resolves?

Comment: @LostJon You are right. I actually talked with the person that wrote this assignment. Apparently, the expect has to be in chai syntax. Now I have to figure out how to integrate pure selenium-webdriver with js so I can control the ui...

Comment: @learningruby347 so it sound like you have a line doing something like `var expect=require('chai').expect`. you can still do something like `expect(clearFieldBtn.isPresent()).to.be.true`

Comment: You are right. There is a similar line of code. It was hidden in the depths of hell..

Comment: you should separate your chai/mocha testing from protractor. protractor will require selenium or chromedrivers and are meant for UI or E2E testing. Mocha/Chai should be used with integration/unit testing IMO. The two in the same spec files dont play nicely. For example, you cant change headers w/ protractor (not really), so API testing is bogus

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried these lines:

```
    clearFieldBtn.isPresent().then(function(bln) {
         expect(bln).toBe(true);
    });

    result.getText().then(function(tmpText) {
         expect(tmpText).toBe('John Smith');
    });
```

If you still get an error on result.getText(), please check the presence of the result object.